# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'MedicalSchemeDetailGrid'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

am getting this error **" Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'MedicalSchemeDetailGrid'. Remove one definition"**

below is my aspx page where i have the datasource

```
                <ContentTemplate>
                <ctls:SearchPanel ID="MedicalSchemeDetailSearchPanel" runat="server" GridID="MedicalSchemeDetailGrid"
                    SearchButtonText="Search" ClearButtonText="Clear" ExpressionLabel="Search Expression"
                    Visible="false" />
                <div class="vsep">
                </div>
                <rwg:BulkEditGridView ID="MedicalSchemeDetailGrid" runat="server" DataMember="MedicalSchemeDetail" OnPageIndexChanging="MedicalSchemeDetailGrid_PageIndexChanging"
                    AllowPaging="true" DataSourceID="DBDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CompanyID,BranchID,DepartmentID,MedicalSchemeID,ItemID,PatientStatus">
                    <HeaderStyle Height="30px" /> here
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Remove 1 of the 2 data sources. One is probably assigned in code behind.

Comment: i have posted my code behind kindly assist me

Answer (score 0):

You have both

```
MedicalSchemeDetailGrid.DataSource = dbSrc;
MedicalSchemeDetailGrid.DataBind();
```

And

```
<rwg:BulkEditGridView ID="MedicalSchemeDetailGrid" DataSourceID="DBDataSource1"
```

You can't have both, remove one (as the error message states)